# Git alias for fetching and checking out remote branch?

Tags: git, alias

I am trying to write a quick alias to checkout and track a remote branch with this syntax

```
git get {branch_name}
```

the correct method to do this would be

```
git checkout --track origin/{branch_name}
```

I tried

```
[alias]
   get = "!sh -c 'git checkout --track origin/$1'"
```

But get a *fatal: missing branch name*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code looks like it's a shell alias (i see $1 substitutions and the sh command). i would suggest adding it as an alias in your .gitconfig file. in that file the "git" command is understood.

```
[alias]
    get = 'checkout --track origin/'
```

(you might need a double slash, escaping and all, not 100% on that)

so calling:

```
$ git get someName
```

will essentially call:

```
git checkout --track origin/someName
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the following alias to your .gitconfig file

```
cto = "!f() { \
    git checkout --track origin/\"$1\"; \
}; f"
```

I use cto (checkout track origin) for alias name and shell command with substitutions to pass in branch name.

You can then use the alias like so

```
git cto my-cool-branch
```

which will be equivlant to

```
git checkout --track origin/my-cool-branch
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works a treat. (Looks like your branches are cooler than mine!)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's already trying to substitute $1. Another thing that could be cause of trouble the sh command in a git alias config. I would use a shell alias instead.